# Why Kotlin's println method doesn't print java.sql.Timestamp correctly?

Tags: java, kotlin, date, datetime, timestamp

Here is the code in **Kotlin**:

```kotlin
val df = java.text.SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy G, HH:mm:ss.S Z")

println(df.format(java.sql.Timestamp(Long.MIN_VALUE)))
println(java.sql.Timestamp(Long.MIN_VALUE))
```

the output is:

```
2 Dec 292269055 BC, 17:47:04.192 +0100
292278994-08-17 08:12:55.192
```

The correct output is the one where `SimpleDateFormat` is used. Notice how almost all date parts are different (year, month, ...) except for the milliseconds.
Why do I have to use SimpleDateFormat to get the correct result?

Any ideas what is going on here?

Comment: The date  `292278994-08-17` seems to be affected by some integer overflow. It doesn't look like before Christ.

Comment: This doesn't look like it has anything to do with Kotlin...

Comment: The results are the same from _Long.MIN_VALUE + 808_ on.

Comment: @lukas.j It does indeed seem to start printing the right value from 808 on (for some weird reason), thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score -1):

The reason Kotlin's println method doesn't print java.sql.Timestamp correctly is because the println method internally calls the toString() method of the object being printed. In the case of java.sql.Timestamp, the default implementation of toString() returns a string representation in the format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS".

In your code, when you call println(java.sql.Timestamp(Long.MIN_VALUE)), the toString() method of Timestamp is invoked, which returns the default format. However, when you call println(df.format(java.sql.Timestamp(Long.MIN_VALUE))), you are explicitly formatting the Timestamp using a SimpleDateFormat object (df), which gives you a custom format.

The discrepancy in the output is because the SimpleDateFormat format (d MMM yyyy G, HH:mm:ss.S Z) you specified in your code is not compatible with the default format of java.sql.Timestamp. The default format of Timestamp does not take into account the era (G) and timezone (Z) format elements.

To print java.sql.Timestamp correctly with your desired format, you can explicitly format it using the SimpleDateFormat object like this:

```
val df = java.text.SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy G, HH:mm:ss.S Z")
val timestamp = java.sql.Timestamp(Long.MIN_VALUE)
println(df.format(timestamp))
```

This will give you the desired output:

2 Dec 292269055 BC, 17:47:04.192 +0100

Comment: "The default format of Timestamp does not take into account the era (G)" Why does it then start taking into account the era (without displaying it) starting from `Long.MIN_VALUE + 808` and up? it works properly from `Long.MAX_VALUE` and going down until `Long.MIN_VALUE + 808`, and then for the rest of the 808 values, it is way off